# Adding One more Parent Attrubute To JSON through Command line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, edit, jq

I want edit the structure of json through Terminal using terminal commands or scripts.
        If I have a json file Structure like this:

```
      {
      "Helloo": [
        {

          "AlbumTitle": {
            "S": "Famous"
          },
          "SongTitle": {
            "S": "Call Me Today"
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "No One You Know"
          }

        },
{

          "AlbumTitle": {
            "S": "Famous1"
          },
          "SongTitle": {
            "S": "Call Me Today1"
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "No One You Know11"
          }

        }
      ],
      "Music": [
        {

          "Album": {
            "S": "Pop Songs"
          },
          "Production": {
            "S": "X-series"
          },
          "Song": {
            "S": "Once upon
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "XYZ"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
```

So here i want add "Putrequest" and "Item" attributes to each item of the array.. So i want the output like this:

```
 {
      "Helloo": [
        {
        PutRequest":{  
            "Item":{ 

          "AlbumTitle": {
            "S": "Famous"
          },
          "SongTitle": {
            "S": "Call Me Today"
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "No One You Know"
          }

        }
        }
        },
{
PutRequest":{  
            "Item":{ 

          "AlbumTitle": {
            "S": "Famous1"
          },
          "SongTitle": {
            "S": "Call Me Today1"
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "No One You Know11"
          }

        }
        }
        }
      ],
      "Music": [
        {
PutRequest":{  
            "Item":{ 
          "Album": {
            "S": "Pop Songs"
          },
          "Production": {
            "S": "X-series"
          },
          "Song": {
            "S": "Once upon
          },
          "Artist": {
            "S": "XYZ"
          }
}
}
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried to use Jq for this but still struggling.. Please help me To add these attributes to json using command prompt or bash/shell scripting.
Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far in jq.

Comment: You know it's not valid JSON right? `"S": "Once upon` <- Missing quote `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually got valid JSON the following jq expression might work for you:

```
map_values(map({"PutRequest": { "Item": .}}))
```

Usage:

```
jq 'map_values(map({"PutRequest": { "Item": .}}))' file.json
```

Breakdown:

```
map_values(           # Map values iterate over an object and assign the 
                      # returned value to the property
  map(                # Map iterate over an array and assign the returned value
                      # to the index, and creates a new array if an object is
                      # mapped
    {                 # Return an object
      "PutRequest": { # With PutRequest as a property
        "Item": .     # And Item, which contains the value (.)
      }
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: @andlrs: Thank u once again.. I did accepted your answer :)

Comment: @Tedd I'm happy that I could help you, now you should read it twice, and rewrite it yourself :-)

Comment: @andlrs: I have one more query here: What i can do using Jq, if i want to change "Hello" to "Stage_Hello" and "Music" to "stage_Music" from above Json.?

Comment: @Tedd Added `| .State_Music = .Music | del(.Music)` to the end of the jq command might work: `jq 'map_values(map({"PutRequest": { "Item": .}})) | .State_Music = .Music | del(.Music)'`

Comment: @andlrs : Thank a lot.. It works.. But one last query.. can we make it generic.. Like: I want to append "Dev_", "Prod_"  to "Hello" and "Music" [like: "Dev_Hello"] According to the requirement whether i want it for Dev/prod.. Like adding conditions.. If its "Dev" then i want "Hello" to be "Dev_Hello"..